# Define a Lambda function as Argument Constraint in Spock

Tags: java, groovy, lambda, mocking, spock

There is a piece of code I want to cover with a unit test

```
public List<Product> fetchProducts() {
   ...
   String userId = anotherObj.getId()
   return caller.call(client -> client.getProducts(userId));
}
```

*note: I'm not able to change that code*

Now, this is the unit test that is working using a wildcard (omitted everything that is unrelated):

```
def anotherObj = Mock( ... )
def caller = Mock( ... )

...

when:
  subject.fetchProducts()

then:
  1 * anotherObj.getId() >> USER_ID
and:
  1 * caller.call(_) >> mockedApiResponse
```

***the problem***

I want to check that the funcion `call` is actually called with a function that recieves a parameter & calls that parameter with the proper argument

***pseudocode***

```
then:
  1 * anotherObj.getId() >> USER_ID
and:
  1 * caller.call( { it(obj -> obj.getProducts(USER_ID)) } ) >> mockedApiResponse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just If someone come across this;

A solution is defining a behaviour to the `caller`mock: when the `caller` is called with an argument, then

- First, that argument is a `Function`
- The mock is actually invoking it with exactly one argument
- That argument is a groovy mock so we'll able to create assertions over it later on.

Code:

```
def anotherObj = Mock( ... )
def caller = Mock( ... )
def client = Mock( ... )

...

when:
  def response = subject.fetchProducts()

then:
  1 * anotherObj.getId() >> USER_ID
and:
  1 * caller.call(_) >> { Function lambda ->
      lambda.apply(client)
      return apiResponse
  }
and:
  1 * client.getProducts(USER_ID)
and:
  response == ...
```

Comment: Technically, the answer is correct. But your test also covers the code without you verifying the interaction on `client.getProducts()`. To me this looks like over-specification. Why do you even care about the internal implementation and not just about testing that the method actually does the right thing? If you ever refactor, you need to adjust the test even though the method still does the same thing. I see no reason to verify that inside a method a specific getter is called. I assume that the client class has its own test, does it not?

Comment: Something else: In your final `and: response == ...` the assertion can only be `response == apiResponse` according to your test code, i.e. you are actually verifying that the subject parametrised with your mock caller actually returns the stubbed result you said it should. That means you are just testing your mock in this case. Maybe it would make more sense to make the client a Spock spy instead of a mock. But it depends on what you want to test. Clearly it does not make sense to check that a mock returns a mock result, though.

Comment: as you said depends on what you are trying to test. This is extremely artificial and the only improvement here is that I can assert the argument of the call at `getProducts()`: `client.getProducts(USER_ID)` (if called with a different argument this test is going to advise me, something wasn't happening before with the wildcard). Anyway, keeping this question at stackoverflow since it could be useful for another person :)